# can I correspond a system assembly version with a dotnet framework version? and how to know if an assembly is included in the framework?

Tags: .net, assemblyversions

By "framework" here, I mean the non-core legacy framework that is now at v 4.8. Not core 1.0-3.0 or versions 5 or 6.

For example, consider Microsoft.Identity.Protocols.dll version 5.2.4.0 vs. 6.7.1.0. Can these be associated with specific versions of the .net framework? Is there a general rule for such a correspondence?

Secondly, can I assume that any assembly that begins "System." is part of the framework?  How about if it begins "Microsoft."?   If the answer is "no", how can I know whether it is, or isnt?  The question behind this question is that I want to know if I need to install a package for the assembly, vs letting the framework provide it.

Comment: If the package supports your framework version, there's no harm in installing it, even if it in fact just contains forwarding information that points back to the framework itself. If the package doesn't support your framework version, the question is moot.

Comment: No and no.  Debug > Windows > Modules, Path column provides a decent hint.  If the file doesn't come from c:\windows\microsoft.net then you definitely have to deploy it yourself.  However, there's always a however, in the past there were some downloadable components that deploy to the GAC.  Microsoft provided a bootstrapper for them, to be used in the installer.  It was an old bad practice and nothing to worry about too much today, you'll always notice when you test the installer.  You do have to test.